# Can geocoder serve a GPS navigation- like app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, gps, rails-geocoder

I want to make a user capable to see his  location as he is moving.
 I am already using geocoder (to geocode by ip his location on login) but i want his pin on the map to be live.Is there a way to make geocoder work in this mode?

Comment: Are trying to build an app for a mobile device (smartphone, tablet) or for all web-browsing capable devices?

Comment: There's 3 components to what you want to do: 1) Gather the user's location, 2) store the location, 3) show the location on a map.  Is it just 1) that you're asking about here?  Your question is very broad at the moment, you should try to focus it on a more specific problem than "help me build my app".

Comment: I am asking for the 1) component. How to gather the user's location. Can i use geocoder??The app is for mobile devices(smartphones&tablets).

Comment: Geocoder is a server-side technology, as it runs in your rails app.  It cannot collect location data from the client:  the client needs to send location data to your app in a request.  There are various ways to get the location, depending on the client, but they are all got IN the client (you **could** try to look up a location from the client's IP address, but this isn't even reliable for fixed location home computers let alone mobile devices).  As IKA asks, what platform is the user going to be using?  If it's for iphone or android, they will have an API for getting the current location.

Comment: The app is for iphone. I already have tried the Ipsearch solution but as you already said doesnt help for this functionality.

Comment: What about the HTML5 Geolocation API? Trying to make an app where nearby users can interact, not sure where to start.